# Flash Builder 4 annoyance (new window every time I build)

Tags: flexbuilder, flash-builder

I have an annoyance that I'm trying to solve on my Windows set up.

I have Flash Builder 4 installed on my MacBook, every time I build my application it opens a web browser window (Safari) and runs the application. If I build the application again it uses the same window that is already up from the previous build and refreshes it, which is exactly what I want to happen.

My issue is with my Windows machine, I have the same exact setup. But when I launch my app it opens up a new browser window/tab (depending on which browser I use) every single time. So after building my app about 25 times, I have 25 windows/tabs open.

Anyone run into this and have a solution? I know that I could just build it and not launch it and manually refresh the browser, but I would LOVE for my Windows setup to work exactly like my Mac setup :). I have tried just about everything, I even install Safari on my Windows machine, but that didn't fix the issue =/

I have a fresh install of Flash Builder 4 on both my Windows machine and my MacBook, I haven't changed any settings in Flash Builder, aside from the workspace directory, on either of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know how annoying this can be ;)

If you are using Firefox I recommend [this addons](http://www.diveintoria.com/preventDuplicateTabs/), if you are using Chrome check you [this one](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ljnhndkfkbcfmfdkfaahkfmiiibaldhd).
Basically this will prevent opening duplicate tabs with the same url.

If you are using Internet Explorer then... you are a very bad person! :)

Comment: So just for the record, does this mean that the annoyance is a window's issue?

Comment: I don't think is a Windows issue. Is rather the way how the browser handles the link given by the external application(Flash Builder). I cannot test right now on Mac but I guess that the same thing happens with Firefox and Chrome on Mac.